# sonar 4.5.4-- Debt definition of rule is invalid exception

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I have my own customized plugins of csharp of version 2.1 when i deployed stylecope plugin in sonar 4.5.4 server, some rules getting exception like below but after removing those rule its working fine. This exception am getting in sonar 4.5.4 but not facing any issues in sonar 4.2 and lesser version. I need to know why this issue occuring and what is mean to say? Please explain. Thanks

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Debt definition on rule 'stylecopcsharp:ConstFieldNamesMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter' is invalid
    at org.sonar.server.rule.DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.remediationFunction(DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.java:135) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.updateRuleDebtDefinitions(DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.java:117) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.complete(DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.java:107) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RuleDefinitionsLoader.load(RuleDefinitionsLoader.java:53) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.start(RegisterRules.java:102) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:590) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:586) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-4.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]`

Comment: You don't mention your plugin version. Can you check to make sure you're using the latest?

Comment: Am using plugin version 2.1. Actually i need to use latest plugin for sonar-dotnet-fxcop plugin but i couldnt able to find the latest sonar fxcop which supports sonar server 4.5.4.@G. Ann - SonarSource Team

Comment: FYI @chethan the `sonarqube` tag is sufficient (no need for sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0 and so on). However, it would be better to also include `c#` or `stylecop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET and C# plugins version 2.1 are not compatible with newer versions of SonarQube (including 4.5.4).

You should really consider upgrading to the latest C# plugin and use the MSBuild SonarQube Runner developed in partnership with Microsoft to analyze all .NET projects: It vastly improves the experience, provides much better analysis results, and is way easier to use.

See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/csharp.html to get started.

The information below is informative only, and will allow you to proceed with an unsupported deprecated version of the C# plugin (which is bad, so think twice :p):

I see that you created your own StyleCop plugin, with the key `stylecopcsharp`: You should define valid SQALE remediation costs for each rule - or SonarQube will refuse to start.

The easiest way is actually to remove all SQALE remediation cost information. Now, if you'd like to keep SQALE, you can have a look at the stack trace and see how SonarQube's validation works: [DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.java#L135](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/4.5.4/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/rule/DeprecatedRulesDefinitionLoader.java#L135)

There could be more obstacles preventing the use of .NET and C# with SonarQube 4.5.4, so again think twice before going this way.

Comment: Hi Dinesh Thank you so much. Just one more question. I need to use sonar dotnet fxcop and sonar dotnet stylecop plugins because i need many rules from fxcop and stylecop and also gendarme(less priority).If i upgrade the plugin version where i can get this rule plugins.

Comment: @chethan FxCop support is built-in in the C# 4.1 plugin, and there is a separate SonarQube StyleCop plugin version 1.1 - http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/lgAW - Gendarme's support however has been dropped since C# 3.x and its supported will not be added back.